# How to return a c# function like in python?

Tags: c#, python, delegates

I'm trying to do something that could be done like so in python:

```
class Spam():
    def print_four_numbers(a, b, c, d):
        print a, b, c, d

class Beacon():
    def bar(SpamInstance):
        return SpamInstance.print_four_numbers

B, S = Beacon(), Spam()
```

The key thing here is that the above code allows me to do this:

```
>>>B.bar(S)(1, 2, 3, 4)
1 2 3 4
```

How can I do something similar with C#? If it changes anything, I need the "print_four_numbers" method to be overloaded 3-4 times. I've read about delegates and events but will they work here (and how)?

Also I know that this could be solved by simply passing all those arguments to `bar()` and "passing them on" to another function, but I dislike having methods with a lot of arguments.

Thanks!

Comment: So you've read about delegates, and they do exactly this, and you're asking how to do this?  It sounds like you *haven't* really read much about delegates at all.  What attempted implementations have you made using delegates?  What problems have you had in using them?  What about the documentation or other online resources have you found confusing?

Comment: @Servy I'm not really sure where and how should I declare those delegates. In python, I don't have to care about return types. In c# though...

Comment: @Servy don't be so mean... sometimes it's really easier to learn something new by example, you don't even have enough grasp of the subject to know exactly what to ask.

Comment: So you looked at the documentation for delegates?  You looked at some example code that uses delegates?  Even after doing that, you still couldn't come up with how to create an instance of a delegate?  I find that *highly* unlikely.  There are simply tons and tons of resources online on this subject.  You've not demonstrated that you've done any research, looked at any exampled, or tried *anything&*.

Comment: @golergka But that's just it.  He *did* know enough to know what to ask for.  He knew he was looking for delegates, and that search term will lead him to *hundreds of thousands* of examples very similar to his own.  If he *didn't* know the terms that he needed to search on then I'd have some sympathy for him, but he clearly *did*, and simply choose not to bother.

Comment: @Servy "So you've been at a lecture about discrete mathematics? You looked at some example exercises? Even after doing that, you still couldn't pass the exam? I find that highly unlikely" - what every professor could easily say

Comment: @Dunno Even if they struggled, I'd certainly expect them to be able to do something other than say, "I have no idea what I'm doing, do it all for me."  You have tried nothing.  You've researched nothing.  You haven't utilized any of the virtually infinite number of existing resources out there.  This isn't' a test, you aren't prohibited from using these existing resources.  If you couldn't remember them, that's one thing, when you're too lazy to look up the solution when you're holding the book that explains it, then that's on *you*.

Comment: geez I really regret asking anything on StackOverflow lately. Of course I could spend a couple of hours trying to figure it out all by myself. But what's the purpose of this site, then? Sorry I've taken your precious time!

Comment: @Dunno You seem to be under the impression that the site is here to just do your work for you.  It is not.  It is here to create a useful repository of knowledge that will be helpful for future visitors.  This question is not doing that.  It's doing nothing other than having someone else putting your own question into google for you, because you just couldn't be bothered.  As for why you would want to do it yourself, you'd do it yourself *to learn how to do it*.  Because when golergka just does your work for you, you don't learn how to program, and can't solve the problem *next time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Spam
{
    public void PrintFourNumbers(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", new[] {a, b, c, d}));
    }
}

class Beacon
{
    public System.Action<int, int, int, int> Bar(Spam instance)
    {
        return instance.PrintFourNumbers;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new Beacon();
        var s = new Spam();
        b.Bar(s)(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }
}
```

The `PrintFourNumbers` method is pretty ugly; it would look much nicer if it accepted an array of integers, but I wanted to keep it as close to example in the question as possible.

Comment: you don't need to create a string array, and call ToString on each number. just `string.Join(" ", new [] { a, b, c, d});` would work